# How to deploy an app I have in Next.js with Prisma on Hostinger and how to connect it to the database?

Tags: database, deployment, prisma, vercel

In the .env folder of my Next.js project with Prisma, it's asking for 'DATABASE_URL,' but Hostinger doesn't provide this URL for external connection. I haven't found a way to deploy with Vercel either. How can this be done? I've also considered simply copying the files to Hostinger or sending them via FTP, but then how would the ORM and the database connection be set up?

I've tried to obtain the URL, but it doesn't seem to be available. I'm exploring alternatives since shared hosting might not be suitable, and I'm considering using a VPS or a GitHub repository. I'm also contemplating using Prisma and Vercel without Hostinger or implementing URL redirection. However, I'm currently stuck at this point because my domain is on Hostinger, and I would like to everage both the hosting and the domain.